# How to Capture Exception in ADF JSFF

Tags: eclipse, exception, oracle-adf

I am currently developing with [Oracle ADF Essentials](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/adfessentials-1719844.html) using [Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html) and [GlassFish 4](https://glassfish.java.net/).

I would like capture an Java `Exception` and properly show it on the screen inside a `JSFF` `Task Flow` view

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the official Oracle Documentation **[Handling Exceptions in Task Flows](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/adf/develop/task-flow-advanced.htm#ADFFD1647)**

Is says

> In the task flow diagram, right-click the activity and choose **Mark Activity > Exception Handler**

Therefore create backing bean with method or create class with a method and convert it to data control. Refer documentation **[Using Method Call Activities](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/adf/develop/task-flow-activities.htm#ADFFD1674)** do drag and drop for a Method call and mark that activity as exception.

Capture the exception which is thrown using ADF **`ControllerContext`** using the following code. I have assumed method name as **showException**

```
public void showException() {
  ControllerContext cc = ControllerContext.getInstance();

  Exception ex = cc.getCurrentViewPort().getExceptionData();
  String message = ex.getMessage();


  FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  FacesMessage facesMessage =
  new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "UTF: " + message, null);
  fc.addMessage(null, facesMessage);

  cc.getCurrentRootViewPort().clearException();
  fc.renderResponse();
}
```